# I would like to receive an Android custom recyclerview click event

Tags: android

I want to receive an Android custom recyclerview click event.
But sometimes click events don't fire
Is there a problem with the source?
I want to do some action by receiving an event when the EditText is clicked.
The source is below
Thank you

I want to receive an Android custom recyclerview click event.
But sometimes click events don't fire
Is there a problem with the source?
I want to do some action by receiving an event when the EditText is clicked.
The source is below
Thank you

```
public class RecyclerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
        implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    public ArrayList<CustomView> mItems;

    private final OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;

    Context mContext;

    public RecyclerListAdapter(Context context, OnStartDragListener dragStartListener, ArrayList<CustomView> item) {
        mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;

        this.mItems = item;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rcy_item_layout, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view, mContext);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) 
    {
        holder.edtPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }


    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

        Context context;
        EditText edtPrice;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView, Context mContext) {
            super(itemView);

            context = mContext;
            edtPrice = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_price);

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide much more details so we can help you

Comment: I'm a beginner What more information do you need?

Comment: Just copy and paste the whole class

Comment: Explain more what must do custom event and when must fire.

Comment: @leegill your code is fine, have you tried to add beak point in onclick method and see if it is called?